# How to make a pause/play button for timer on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my pause and play button function on javascript, but I don't exactly know the logic behind all of it

I have tried putting the `clearInterval()` method in my `pauseTimer` function

```
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var startSound = document.getElementById("audio"); 
var timerSound = document.getElementById("timer");
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
var middlebuttons = document.getElementsByClassName("middlebuttons");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
var playButton = document.getElementById('play');


function pauseTimer(){
    clearInterval();
    alert("Pause button");
  }

function playTimer(){
    alert("Play button");
}

function countDown(minutes){
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes;
    function tick(){

        var current_minutes = mins - 1;

        seconds --;
        counter.innerHTML = current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        if(seconds > 0){
            setTimeout(tick, 10);
        } else {
            if(mins > 1){
                countDown(mins - 1);
            }
            else if (mins && seconds === 0 ){
               timerSound.play();
                buttons();
            }
        }
    }    
    tick();

  }

pauseButton.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer, playAudio );
playButton.addEventListener('click', playTimer, playAudio );
```

Comment: `setTimeout` and `clearInterval`? You should probably use `setInterval`. Check out the usage of `clearInterval` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a thoroughly commented suggested solution. It uses a `totalSeconds` variable as the counter's source of truth.

The reason the `timer` variable is needed is because `clearInterval` wants to be told *which* interval to clear.

There's no "stop" button in this demo. If you want to reset the timer while it's running, just refresh the page.
(And it doesn't include any functions to play sounds, but you could add those at the appropriate points in the code.)

```js
// Defines identifiers for accessing HTML elements
const minutesInput = document.getElementById("minutesInput"),
      startButton = document.getElementById("startButton"),
      pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton"),
      unpauseButton = document.getElementById("unpauseButton"),
      counterDiv = document.getElementById("counterDisplay");

// Adds listeners and declares global variables
startButton.addEventListener('click', start);
pauseButton.addEventListener('click', pauseTimer);
unpauseButton.addEventListener('click', runTimer);
let totalSeconds; // global variable to count down total seconds
let timer; // global variable for setInterval and clearInterval 

//Disables buttons that are not needed yet
disable(pauseButton);
disable(unpauseButton);


// Defines functions that get the minutes and seconds for display
function getMinutes(totalSeconds){
  return Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60); // Gets quotient rounded down 
}

function getSeconds(totalSeconds){
 let seconds = totalSeconds % 60; // Gets remainder after division
 return (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds) // Inserts "0" if needed
}


// Defines functions that manipulate the countdown
function start(){
  totalSeconds = minutesInput.value * 60; // Sets initial value of totalSeconds based on user input
  counterDiv.innerHTML = getMinutes(totalSeconds) + ":" + getSeconds(totalSeconds); // Initializes display
  disable(minutesInput); disable(startButton); // Toggles buttons
  runTimer();
}

function runTimer(){
  // Is the main timer function, calls `tick` every 1000 milliseconds
  timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  disable(unpauseButton); enable(pauseButton); // Toggles buttons
}

function tick(){
  if(totalSeconds > 0){
    totalSeconds--; // Decreases total seconds by one
    counterDiv.innerHTML = getMinutes(totalSeconds) + ":" + getSeconds(totalSeconds); // Updates display
  }
  else{
    // The timer has reached zero. Let the user start again. 
    enable(minutesInput); enable(startButton);
    disable(pauseButton); disable(unpauseButton);
  }
}

function pauseTimer(){
  // Stops calling `tick` and toggles buttons
  clearInterval(timer);
  disable(pauseButton); enable(unpauseButton);
}


// Defines functions to disable and re-enable HTML elements
function disable(element){ element.setAttribute("disabled",""); }
function enable(element){ element.removeAttribute("disabled"); }
```

```css
counter{ height: 1em; width: 2em; margin: 0.4em; border: 1px solid grey }
```

```html
<label>
  How many minutes?:
  <input type="number" id="minutesInput" value="1" />
</label>
<br />

<button id="startButton">Start</button>
<button id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
<button id="unpauseButton">Continue</button>
<div id="counterDisplay"></div>
```